# wordpress fetch data greater than id 100

Tags: wordpress

we are trying to fetch data from WordPress post for one no of rows there is no issue but we want to use where clause in query. We want to fetch all rows whose id is greater than 100. we tried compare but later we came to know that compare is for meta_query. we dont want to use meta_query column as there is no data in that column.
we tried to increase the offset and i was hopeful that it will work but it did not work

```
$paginate_by = '1000';
    $offset = 0;
    $has_more_images = true;

    while ( $has_more_images ) {
        $args = array(
            'p'              => $comp_last_id, // is 100
            'posts_per_page' => $paginate_by,
            'offset'         => 0,
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_status'    => 'any',
            'orderby'        =>'ID',
            'order'          => 'ASC'

        );


        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $the_query -> have_posts () ) {
            while ( $the_query -> have_posts () ) {
                $the_query -> the_post ();
                $idall = get_the_ID ();
            }
        }
        $args['offset'] += $paginate_by;        
            }
```

any help in how to fetch all rows whose id greater than 100 will be great

Answer (score 1):

Try using posts_where filter:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where

Where for conditions that apply only to your query so that all query are not affected. conditions like is_page(), is_single(), etc